# Cannot configure Hibernate with MySQL and TomEE in Java EE (wrong dialect?)

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, apache-tomee, java-ee-8

I am learning Java EE and for 2 days already I've been struggling with configuration of Hibernate to work with MySQL database on a TomEE server in a simple Java EE web application.

- Hibernate version: 5.4.10.Final (core and entity-manager dependencies)
- Java EE API: 8.0
- MySQL version: 8.0.19
- TomEE version: 8.0.1 (TomEE Embedded in tomee-embedded-maven-plugin)

I have 2 simple entities: Car and Seat, with the uni-directional @OneToMany relation from Car to Seat(s). Color and EngineType are plain enums, while Specification is a value object for these 2 enums). NOTE: FetchType.EAGER is used in the @OneToMany for learning purposes, I am familiar that this is not a good solution normally.

When I try to configure the persistence.xml file, alghouth specifying everything "as for MySQL", **it seems that Hibernate still uses the default HSQLDB syntax/dialect/engine** and as a result, I recieve **errors during schema creation**:

```
[INFO] TomEE embedded started on localhost:8080
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
Hibernate: alter table Seat drop foreign key FKkkm9pdx9e1t9jva76n9tqhhqv
mar 06, 2020 1:48:31 PM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl handleException
WARN: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "alter table Seat drop foreign key FKkkm9pdx9e1t9jva76n9tqhhqv" via JDBC Statement
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table Seat drop foreign key FKkkm9pdx9e1t9jva76n9tqhhqv" via JDBC Statement
(...)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.SEAT
(...)
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.SEAT     // what is going on here???
```

and for later Hibernate SQL commands while creating DDL, I have also:

```
Hibernate: create table Car (identifier bigint not null auto_increment, color varchar(255), engineType varchar(255), primary key (identifier)) engine=InnoDB
mar 06, 2020 1:48:31 PM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl handleException
WARN: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "create table Car (identifier bigint not null auto_increment, color varchar(255), engineType varchar(255), primary key (identifier)) engine=InnoDB" via JDBC Statement
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table Car (identifier bigint not null auto_increment, color varchar(255), engineType varchar(255), primary key (identifier)) engine=InnoDB" via JDBC Statement
(...)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: AUTO_INCREMENT
(...)
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: unexpected token: AUTO_INCREMENT   // definitely something messed up, this is a correct MySQL token
```

When I omit all "MySQL stuff" (driver and dialect), and make Hibernate use default HSQLDB, it works fine... The DDL for HSQLDB is created well.

I tried many different configurations and replacements googling it over the web and SO, but not found any hint why Hibernate still uses non-MySQL syntax (but I am not 100% sure that this is the direct cause of the issue).

**I attempted to specify the datasource in resources.xml file under webapp, but it doesn't change anything.** Additionally, I checked if HSQLDB could be excluded from Maven build, but it ships with hibernate-core, so it's not easily achievable and perhaps could also not help.

I have previously used Hibernate with Spring and SpringBoot, but with Java EE I am totally lost here, that's why I asked the question.

**Could anyone help with the issue and give some advices on the correct configuration of all this?**

My persistence.xml under resources/META-INF looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.2"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="my-persistence-unit" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:openejb/Resource/myJtaDatabase</jta-data-source>
        <!-- Entity classes -->
        <class>com.example.javaeecourse.entity.Car</class>
        <class>com.example.javaeecourse.entity.Seat</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javaeecourse?serverTimezone=UTC" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="admin" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
            <property name="tomee.jpa.factory.lazy" value="true" />
            <!--<property name="tomee.jpa.cdi=false" value="false" />-->
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Car entity:

```java
package com.example.javaeecourse.entity;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import static com.example.javaeecourse.entity.Car.FIND_ALL;

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "cars")
@NamedQuery(name = FIND_ALL, query = "SELECT car FROM Car car")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Car {

    public static final String FIND_ALL = "Car.findAll";

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long identifier;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Color color;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private EngineType engineType;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "car", nullable = false)
    private Set<Seat> seats = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Seat entity:

```java
package com.example.javaeecourse.entity;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "seats")
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Seat {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String seatMaterial;

    public Seat(String seatMaterial) {
        this.seatMaterial = seatMaterial;
    }
}
```

CarManufacturer class (@Stateless EJB, where EntityManager is called):

```java
package com.example.javaeecourse.boundary;

import com.example.javaeecourse.control.CarFactory;
import com.example.javaeecourse.entity.Car;
import com.example.javaeecourse.entity.CarCreatedEvent;
import com.example.javaeecourse.entity.Specification;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.enterprise.event.Event;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import java.util.List;

@Stateless
public class CarManufacturer {

    @Inject
    CarFactory carFactory;

    @Inject
    Event<CarCreatedEvent> carCreatedEvent;

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    public Car manufactureCar(Specification specification) {
        Car car = carFactory.createCar(specification);
        entityManager.persist(car);
        carCreatedEvent.fire(new CarCreatedEvent(car.getIdentifier()));
        return car;
    }

    public List<Car> retrieveCars() {
        return entityManager.createNamedQuery(Car.FIND_ALL, Car.class).getResultList();
    }
}
```

CarFactory class, which instantiates the entity:

```java
package com.example.javaeecourse.control;

import com.example.javaeecourse.entity.*;

import javax.inject.Inject;

public class CarFactory {

    @Inject
    @DefaultCarColor
    Color randomCarColor;

    @Inject
    @DefaultCarEngineType
    EngineType randomCarEngineType;

    public Car createCar(Specification specification) {
        Car car = new Car();
        car.setColor(specification.getColor() == null ? randomCarColor : specification.getColor());
        car.setEngineType(specification.getEngineType() == null ? randomCarEngineType : specification.getEngineType());
        Seat seat = new Seat("Leather");
        car.getSeats().add(seat);
        return car;
    }
}
```

pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>javaeecourse</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>Java EE Course App</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax</groupId>
      <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
      <version>8.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
      <version>8.0.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.4.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
      <version>5.4.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>1.18.12</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>javaeecourse</finalName>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.tomee.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>tomee-embedded-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>8.0.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: As you provide the datasource with the `jta-datasource` element you don't have to provide any of the `hibernate.connection` properties. Check that the datasource is configured properly on TomeEE and that the jdbc driver is there.

Comment: @areus Thank you very much for the hint! I was able to resolve the case (posted an answer for future readers of the question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the hint provided by @areus in the question comment, I was able to resolve the case. I am posting an answer here if anyone had a similar issue in the future.

There was 1 major issue and 1 "bad practice" issue.

The main problem was that I was using a JTA transaction type and referenced the jta-data-source by JNDI name, but the resources.xml was located under webapp instead of resources/META-INF.
**After I moved the resource.xml to the META-INF**, the database could be properly created and entities were persisted.

Additionally, in my configuration, I have used a deprecated JDBC Driver for MySQL 8. According to [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-api-changes.html) doc, since MySQL 8.0, the driver is now `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`, not `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`.

I also removed the unnecessary properties, so the config is now quite clear and everything works fine.

resources/META-INF/persistence.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.2"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="my-persistence-unit" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/javaeecourse</jta-data-source>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
            <property name="tomee.jpa.factory.lazy" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

resources/META-INF/resources.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tomee>
<Resource id="jdbc/javaeecourse" type="javax.sql.DataSource">
    JdbcDriver = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    JdbcUrl = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javaeecourse?serverTimezone=UTC
    UserName = root
    Password = admin
    jtaManaged = true
</Resource>
</tomee>
```

Here is also a [great article](https://dzone.com/articles/resource-local-vs-jta-transaction-types-and-payara) regarding the JTA/RESOURCE_LOCAL transaction types as well as jta-data-source and non-jta-data-source configuration, which helped me understand the details.